# buying car in USA with Canadian driver licence

Tags: usa, canada, driving-license, car

If I live in USA now, but have a Canadian driver licence, can I buy and register car here or I need to register and get car insurance in Canada?

I works in US by TN visa. I applied for SSN, but didn't get it yet.

Question is: US driver licence is necessary for car registration? Or Canadian is okay?

Comment: If you are a US resident, you are very likely violating the law of the state where you reside.  Most states have a rule that within 30 days of moving there (or some similar period), you must apply for a driver's license from that state.  In other words, most states do not allow their residents to drive with a license from another jurisdiction.

Comment: I'm still less than 30 days here, just wonder if I can buy car before I get US driver licence.

Comment: The quickest way to find out is probably to ask a car dealer, or, if you want to buy one in a private sale, ask the motor vehicles office in your state.

Comment: How did you solve this in the end? Maybe you could put in an answer to help future users? And could you please specify which US state you are/were in?

Comment: @mts,  it depends on the state. I was in RI, used Canadian car first, then got RI driver licence.  It isn't answer actually, just workaround.